# Running tests in parallel on GitHub does not generate Allure report for all test file. Only generate for the last test file

Tags: github, github-actions, puppeteer, allure, jest-puppeteer

When I run these tests locally or in sequence on GitHub it generate Allure Report but when I run it parallel using three different GitHub instance it generate only result for the last executed test file.

```
on:
  workflow_dispatch:
jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    env:
        STAGE_USER_NAME: ${{ secrets.STAGE_USER__EMAIL}}
        STAGE_USER_PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.STAGE_USER_PASSWORD}}

    strategy:
      matrix:
        node-version: [18.14.0]
        test-file:
                  - bprod.test.js
                  - login.test.js
                  - Facebook.test.js
 
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v3
    - name: Use Node.js ${{ matrix.node-version }}
      uses: actions/setup-node@v3
      with:
        node-version: ${{ matrix.node-version }}
        cache: 'npm'
    - run: npm install
      run: npx jest ${{ matrix.test-file }} jest --reporters default jest-allure --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --testTimeout=300000
      continue-on-error: true
   
    - run: npm run alluregenerate
    - name: Upload a Build Artifact
      if: always()
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2-preview
      with: 
          name: report-${{ github.run_number }}
          path: allure-report
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you name the artifact, chose a name that is less ambiguous <sup>1</sup> to not that easily risk to use the same name for different artifacts.

For example, this can be achieved by using a date from the matrix context:

```yaml
    - name: Upload a Build Artifact
      if: always()
      uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2-preview
      with: 
          name: report-${{ github.run_number }}-${{ matrix.test-file }}
          path: allure-report
```

*(artifact name appended with `test-file` from `matrix` context)*

Alternatively, give each test report a different name and make those reports the artifacts (e.g. junit xml files), then have a collecting step obtaining all reports and run allure on all of them (e.g. a directory, c.f.<sup>1</sup>).

---

1. > Each artifact behaves as a file share. Uploading to the same artifact multiple times in the same workflow can overwrite and append already uploaded files

   from: [Uploading to the same artifact - upload-artifact - actions](https://github.com/actions/upload-artifact#uploading-to-the-same-artifact)

Comment: Thank you so much @hakre. its working now. Just have one more question. Can we generate a combine report for all of them?

Comment: @ShadowWalker: Yes, it is said that you can put multiple files from the test reports  into one directory and then generate the allure report from it, e.g. see here: https://docs.qameta.io/allure-report/#_usage_8